# remove the additional price (+0,00) from the bundle product in magento

Tags: magento

When I create a bundle price in magento there is a additional price added behind the product. In the order & email... I only want to show the price from the main bundled product and not from al the products in the bundle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite catalog/product/price.phtml - and replace bundled price there.